# when UIActivityViewController is dismissed, all pushed view controllers are popped as well

Tags: swift, navigation, uiactivityviewcontroller

i have a tab bar controller with view controllers imbedded in navigation controllers. when another view controller is pushed on one of navigation controller and UIActivityViewController is presented there to share a link to app store, when actions are completed and the UIActivityViewController is dismissed, all pushed view controllers are popped from the stack except from the first one.

Anyone had the same problem?

```
    if let name = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/appname"), !name.absoluteString.isEmpty {
        let objectsToShare = [name]
        let activityVC =  UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.view.backgroundColor = .white
        present(activityVC, animated: true) // activityVC is presented on viewcontroller that is pushed on nav controller stack
    }
```